# to our chagrin meaning and structure

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, parts-of-speech

Consider:

> After a perfunctory glance at our plan, to our chagrin Ed snorted that our idea was stupid.

1. > What the part-of-speech is "to our chagrin" ?
2. > Can we say always "to our **[adjective (lucky, adroit)]** we win/fail to ..."

Comment: Have you tried looking "*chagrin*" up in the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, and there is nothing answering question 1 and 3

Comment: I use only Oxford dictionary

Comment: @VictorBazarov Is it off-topic ? If so, I delete it immediately

Comment: @VictorBazarov I've deleted question 2

Comment: This is one I use for quick look-ups: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chagrin , or just in Google "define chagrin" (http://www.google.com/search?q=define+chagrin)

Comment: @VictorBazarov Also useful: [onelook.com/?w=chagrin](http://www.onelook.com/?w=chagrin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supplement Stoney's answer...

No, you can't say "***to our {adjective}***".  You need a *noun* there.  For instance,

> *To our **satisfaction**, we (did something right this time)...*
>   *To our **embarrassment**, we (failed to do something right)...*

Comment: Sorry, Mr Bazarov ! to our {adjective} was a blatant mistake. I was very tired at 3:40 AM by the local time zone.

Answer (score 2):

*To our chagrin* is a phrase, not a part of speech, which is a term designating the categories under which we classify individual words.

*Chagrin* is a noun, the head of the noun phrase *our chagrin*, which is the object of the preposition *to*.

The name of the syntactic function served by the preposition phrase *to our chagrin* is controversial. Traditional grammar would say that the PP is an 'adverbial' (or 'adverbial phrase' or 'adverb phrase') and that it modifies the verb *snorted*. Neo-traditionalists would say it's an adverbial modifying the predicate. A lot of modernists would call it an 'adjunct', while others might move it into the category of 'supplement' or 'disjunct'; and they would disagree over whether it modifies the predicate or the clause.

Whatever you call it, the general tenor is clear: Ed's snorting that our idea was stupid distressed and humiliated us.

Comment: Just put snorted in italics for you. Hope that's ok:)

Comment: Oh, Sorry, dear Stoney ! to our {adjective} was a blatant mistake. I was very tired at 3:40 AM by the local time zone. I feel I am stupid.